# Ruby on Rails - before_action with condition only when one attribute has been changed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, before-filter

In my application I've `Post` model with attributes `title` & `price` etc.

I have 2 `before_action`s that I want to run **only** when `title` has changed & other one **only** when `price` has changed.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_update :do_something_with_title
  before_update :do_something_with_price

  def do_something_with_title
    // my code for title here
  end

  def do_something_with_price?
    // my code for price here
  end
```

I know I can use `changed?` and give `before_action` a `if:` condition, but this will apply when any attribute in `post` has changed and not only when `title` & `price` has changed.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `title_changed?` or `price_changed?`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
  before_update :do_something_with_title, if: :title_changed?
  before_update :do_something_with_price, if: :price_changed?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
  before_update :do_something_with_title, if: :title_changed?
  before_update :do_something_with_price, if: :price_changed?
  ...
end
```

or

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base    
  before_update { |post| post.do_something_with_title if post.title_changed? }
  before_update { |post| post.do_something_with_price if post.price_changed? }
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Mihai. I've only one question. What is difference with Frede's (other answer) answer and yours? Which one is more efficient and better practice? Thanks

Comment: It's just a difference in wording. Now that I think about it, I suppose that I prefer the `if:` way.

Comment: Thanks @Miahi, You prefer `:do_something_with_title, if: :logo_ori_title_changed?` over `before_update { |post| post.do_something_with_title if post.title_changed? }` ?

Comment: You shouldnt use a block to call only one method, its the same as `before_update :do_something_with_title, if: :title_changed?`, if you want to execute multiple methods it will have sense to use a block